# Apply multiple formula in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to add multiple formula in a sharepoint list. 
For example in a leave application, if `leave type`="sick", employee should not apply in previous date and if `leave type`="vacation", employee should not apply more than 5 days, etc.
In easy way I can say, I want to use multiple formula in List or how I can apply in Sharepoint 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 ways:

1- If you are building a custom form to add or edit your leave request, in this case you can add this validation in your web part UI and code behind.

2- If you are using the OOB SharePoint List UI, then you should build an item event receiver and handles the `ItemAdding` event, and set the validation message and `Cancel` property accordingly, you can still add this validation with the first option as an extra validation

This [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/) explains how to create an event receiver